# Showing the divergence of $ \int_0^{\infty} \frac{1}{1+\sqrt{t}\sin(t)^2}  dt$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, integration, improper-integrals

How can I show the divergence of

$$ \int_0^x \frac{1}{1+\sqrt{t}\sin(t)^2}  dt$$

as $x\rightarrow\infty?$

Comment: After word from the chat, it appears using \mathrm is fine. I just had not seen it used often (and I find it ugly!). Sorry I removed the mathrm in your post, feel free to add it back.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For $t \gt 0$:

$$
1 + t \ge 1 + \sqrt{t}\sin^2t
$$

Or:

$$
\frac{1}{1 + t} \le \frac{1}{1 + \sqrt{t}\sin^2t}
$$

Now consider:

$$
\int_0^x \frac{dt}{1 + t} \le \int_0^x \frac{dt}{1 + \sqrt{t}\sin^2t}
$$

The LHS diverges as $x \to +\infty$, so the RHS does too.

Comment: Thank you for your answers! I am realizing that my question is trivial, why couldn't I find this simple inequality alone!

Answer (score 3):

Use $1+\sqrt{t}\sin^2(t)\leqslant1+\sqrt{t}$ uniformly over $t$.